# Items on a circle

Tags: sass

I'm trying to put hexagons made with CSS around a circle. I already got the circle and the hexagons (they are stocked on top of each other), I just can't get the code of organizing them to work (it's on the CSS part of the code). https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLo7D.jpg (I'm aiming this effect).

```css
$darkPrimary: #ffa000;
$primaryYellow: #ffc107;
$lightPrimaryColor: #ffecb3;
$darkGray: #212121;
$redOrange: #ff5722;
$lightGray: #757575;
$dividerColor: #bdbdbd;
// $rot // rotation for the current item
$nb-items: 4;
$angle: (360deg / $nb-items); // angle between two items
// $nb-items // number of item
$rot: 0;
$circle-size: 21.875em;
@mixin placingElements () {
  @for $i from 1 through $nb-items {
    .shapes__circle:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      // Rotate the axis
      rotate: ($rot * 1);
      // Move the item from the center
      translate: $circle-size / 2;
      // Rotate the item back to its default position
      rotate: ($rot * -1);
    }
    $rot: $rot+$angle;
  }
  //Increments the '$rot' variable for the next item
}

.shapes {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  &__circle {
    @include placingElements();
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    border: 19px solid $primaryYellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  &__hexagon {
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
    background: $redOrange;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: 90px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    z-index: 2;
    &::before {
      content: "";
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: -45px;
      left: 0;
      border-left: 60px solid transparent;
      border-right: 60px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 45px solid $redOrange;
    }
    &::after {
      content: "";
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -45px;
      left: 0;
      border-left: 60px solid transparent;
      border-right: 60px solid transparent;
      border-top: 45px solid $redOrange;
    }
    &--inside-img {
      position: absolute;
      height: 55px;
      width: 55px;
      left: 25%;
      top: 32%;
    }
    &--inside-text {
      position: absolute;
      top: -14%;
      left: 5%;
      font-family: 'Overpass Mono', monospace;
      font-size: 1rem;
      color: $darkGray;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shapes__circle">

  <div class="shapes shapes__hexagon">
    <p class="shapes__hexagon--inside-text">Ferramentas</p>
    <img class="shapes__hexagon--inside-img" src="./assets/img/ferramentas.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="shapes shapes__hexagon">
    <p class="shapes__hexagon--inside-text">Ferramentas</p>
    <img class="shapes__hexagon--inside-img" src="./assets/img/ferramentas.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="shapes shapes__hexagon">
    <p class="shapes__hexagon--inside-text">Ferramentas</p>
    <img class="shapes__hexagon--inside-img" src="./assets/img/ferramentas.png" alt="">
  </div>


  <div class="shapes shapes__hexagon">
    <p class="shapes__hexagon--inside-text">Ferramentas</p>
    <img class="shapes__hexagon--inside-img" src="./assets/img/ferramentas.png" alt="">
  </div>


</div>
<!-- __section-img--circle -->
```

Comment: Drawing an example in MS Paint would go a long way in explaining what kind of effect you're going for.

Comment: That's the effect I'm going for http://imgur.com/Sv82DB0
I already got the circle and the hexagons (they are stocked on top of each other), I just can't get the code of organizing them to work (it's on the CSS part of the code).

Comment: I've written something exactly like that, but in JavaScript, would that be okay?

Comment: And is there always just going to be four items or is it dynamic, like there could be 5, 6 etc?

Comment: It's always going to be 4 items, yes it's ok... But with JavaScript I was planning on giving it movement like a wheel, everytime you click on an item it comes to the right where the hexagon with the puzzle piece is and opens the text you see on the side.